# Delannoy numbers representation

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to show 
$$f(n,n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose i}{n+i-1\choose i}$$
for $f(n,n)$ the central delannoy number.
I am stuck at the following. We have
$${2n-k\choose k,n-k,n-k}=\frac{(2n-k)!}{(n-k)!(n-k)!k!}=\frac{(2n-k)!n!}{(n-k)!(n-k)!k! n!}={2n-k\choose n}{n\choose k}$$
the number of ways to get to $(n,n)$ with a fixed number of diagonal steps $k$.

Then we sum over $k$ or $i$
$$f(n,n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{2n-i\choose n}{n\choose i}$$
not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sum is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n-k}{n-k} \binom{n}{n-k}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Reverse the order of this sum with the substitution $i=n-k$ and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n+i}{i} \binom{n}{i}.
\end{eqnarray*}
(Check the first formula needs $n-1 \rightarrow n $) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number#Central_Delannoy_numbers_2